# Hybrid OpenId OAuth with Spring Security

Tags: spring, oauth, openid, hybrid

I am trying to determine if Hybrid OpenId + OAuth is supported in spring and if anyone knows of an example or tutorial that illustrates its usage. After many google searches I see no indication of support.

Thanks
Pete

Comment: A link to provide more information would help.  I think you are talking about some extensions to OpenID 2.0 that are friendly with OAuth 1.0a?

Comment: I am referring to the OpenId+OAuth Hybrid extensions outlined here...https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#oauth

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I don't know of any samples using Spring Security, but please let me know if you find one.  I think Google are putting more effort into OpenIDConnect now (http://openid.net/connect/) so that might also be a good place to focus efforts.